# How does React.js handle CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am attending Bootcamp on Scrimba and they are using the online platform. In React course, the CSS file, while I am working locally, I use `index.css` file and then in the `index.js` file I import it:

```
// CSS File
import "./index.css";
```

But I need to understand please how React deals with CSS file?

Why we don't use the normal `main.css` file in the `index.html`? How is it translated into that in the `index.html` file and there is no link for style sheet?

[image]

Comment: The Project structure

Comment: Your React bundle tool will bundle the CSS once you `import` it. This works both in online editors but also on your local machine, depending how you set up your React project.

Answer (score 1):

> how it is translated into that in the index.html file and there is no link for style sheet

If you pay close attention, there is even no `<script>` in the HTML file to load your JS application, but it still works!

As implied by [Kokodoko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049023/how-is-react-js-act-with-css-file/75052849#comment132441051_75049023) in the question comments, some React tooling is at work here. It is usually based on webpack build engine, which uses loaders and plugins to handle different types of files (including your CSS), and to generate an HTML file based on your template, but with injected `<script>` and `<link>` (or `<style>`, depending on your actual loaders and their configuration).

There would be too much to cover if you want more explanations, but there are a lot of resources that describe the history and how it works in details. See e.g.:

- webpack concepts: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/
- HtmlWebpackPlugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/

BTW, Angular works this way as well, regarding bundling and injection of script and style into HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ghybs &  Kokodoko  as well .. Thanks Guys